# On mac visual studio 2022 how to publish to GitHub, add GitHub username and password

Tags: github-for-mac, visual-studio-mac-2022

[image]Hi,
I was trying to upload into GitHub, I created a GitHub repository. On VS 2022 for mac I only have the Git tab and when I publish I get the no remote target set, second image. I don't know how to set the remote and change the username and password for Github on the VS 2022 for mac.

Comment: I only know how to do it in code git remote set-url origin http//blah.git or git remote add origin http//blah.git. to set username and password its git config

Comment: git config user.name "your username" git config user.password "your password"

Comment: Were you able to figure out a way to do it though the UI? Or is it only through bash?